# c# references not installed in monodevelop

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I have had to update my laptop, and updated to Ubuntu 17.04. I installed monodevelop so that I could continue development of a project I started work on in C#.
I had problems initially with monodevelop crashing when I opened any of my previous projects. Now it has opened one, under the "references" list, I have all the following highlighted as not installed:-

- atk-sharp
- gdk-sharp
- glade-sharp
- glib-sharp
- gtk-sharp
- Mono.Posix
- pango-sharp
- System

I have looked online to see if I can find an answer to no avail, so my apologies if I have done something silly, but any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe you don't install the mono package.

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, and my apologies for the delay. I had tried this before writing - and I tried it again to no avail. :-(

Answer (score 0):

MonoDevelop's install procedure has changed from version 5 onwards. It's now a Flatpak install. See [here](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/linux/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and my apologies for the delay in replying.
I already have Monodevelop 5.10 installed and it has this problem, so presumably, it uses flatpack. :-(

Comment: Ah my apologies, I put you wrong. I think version 6 is flatpak’d. If you didn’t use flatpak to install it then v5 won’t be. :-/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried the link you supplied, and this is the result I got:-
flatpak install --user --from https://download.mono-project.com/repo/monodevelop.flatpakref
error: App com.xamarin.MonoDevelop, branch stable is already installed
My apologies, but what have I done wrong?
Thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have only tonight installed MonoDevelop on Ubuntu. All those in your list are already installed by default, with the exception of glade-sharp.

I followed the instructions here: ( http://www.monodevelop.com/download/ ) which is reproduced below (at the time of writing, this is for version 7.5 (7.5.0.1254)):

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https dirmngr
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu vs-bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-vs.list
sudo apt update
```

I am yet to find a solution for `glade-sharp`